# Brownian motion on sphere proof?

Tags: calculus, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

proving the brownian motion on the sphere equation 
the

stratonovich form differential equation 
$$\partial X=n(X)\times \partial B$$
the equation in ito's form becomes 
$$dX=n(X)\times dB+H(X)n(X)dt$$
where mean curvature is given by: $$H(X)=-\frac{1}{2}(div \ n)(x)$$ 
where $X$ is a brownian motion process in $\mathbb{R^3}$.$n(X)$ is a unit normal to the sphere .

for a unit sphere parameterized by $\theta ,\phi$ 
$$x=\cos \theta \sin\phi,y=\sin\theta\sin\phi,z=\cos \phi$$
the normal to the surface
$$n(X)=\cos\theta\sin\phi ,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos \phi$$
but i am doubtful about how the representation of the vector be

$$d(\cos\theta\sin\phi ,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos \phi)=(\cos\theta\sin\phi ,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos \phi)\times dB +(\cos\theta\sin\phi ,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos \phi)dt $$

$$$$

mean curvature $$H(X)=1 $$ for a sphere .

the result in the book are given

as where $B,W $ are the independent motion

$$d\phi = dB +\frac{1}{2}\cot\phi d\phi$$

$$\theta _t =W\big{(}\int^{t}_{0}(\sin \phi_u )^{-2} du\big{)}$$

any help will be thank full , i am mainly confused with the vector part representation.